# Is the ability to extreme resizing the chat input box intended?

Tags: discussion, chat

That you can shrink chat input box to 0 or 1 character length?

[image: chat pic]

Comment: Big input box is for horses, small input box is for cricket emoji. Customize to fit your needs!

Comment: This is a browser feature, not a site design feature.

Comment: Yes, that is normal by default if the textarea's resize style is set to "both" and there is no set width or height.

Comment: Now, we need to extend it to see how large it will become.

Comment: What is that? An input box for ants?

Comment: @Samuel Liew: No *minimum* width or height.

Comment: @BoltClock I wanted to put (min-) as well but I thought that was implied by width/height

Comment: @Samuel Liew: Well, it's what the user *expects* to be the minimum, since there actually is a set width/height, which is what you see by default.

Comment: I understand how the width of text box could be intended. But I failed to see how this is a bad question (almost double digitally downvoted). Is curiosity not encouraged on stackoverflow?

Comment: I didn't vote on this question, but I can imagine that some users could feel a question about basic browser controls is not particularly usefu since it's expected you had encountered this in many places around the web nowadays; and they voted accordingly. On the plus side, you got 4 moderators and one community manager involved in your question!

Comment: Yeah, that’s like telling the wrongly incarcerated that she should be flattered because 300 strong Navy SEALs have been dispatched for the capture.

Comment: Curiosity is fine, but don't expect a warm reception unless it's about something that matters ;)

Answer (score 5):

Of course this is normal. Any size you want is good. This is not something that the site's design should be imposing on users.

It's your decision. It would be strange if something that allowed you to change its size had arbitrary constraints on that size.

This is nothing to worry about.